# Flutter, customize keyboard

Tags: flutter

In flutter, is it possible to customize the keyboard keys. For example, I want to disable , - and |_| keys in this keyboard, so that TextField only allows numbers.
[image: Snapshot of keyboard]

Answer (score 5):

You can disable the native keyboard by intercepting the PlatformChannel.

I wrote the plugin [cool-ui](https://github.com/Im-Kevin/cool_ui) to achieve the effect.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can change your keyboard type using  for exemple

> keyboardType: TextInputType.number,

or you can try to build your custom  Keyboard.

this plugin can be goood [keyboard_actions](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/keyboard_actions)  to add  functionality to the existing keyboard.

Comment: yes i did use TextInputType...that's how this keyboard came up... but , - aren't of use if currency has to be typed in...